# Adjacent synchronized blocks

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, condition-variable

I'm trying, for academic purpose, to implement something similar to Java high level locks, using the low level mechanism.

I want to implement a different semantics, in which the signaler thread has to wait until the signaled terminates its critical regional, but when the signaled terminates, the signaler has the precedence in order to get the lock.

My doubt is the following: in the attached code, the presence of two adjacent synchronized block is a problem?

I tried to solve the problem used the boolean modified in the synchronized sections, but because the sections locked on different things, I'm not sure about this solution.

```
public class FIFOLock {
    private final Queue<QueueElement> entrySet;
    private boolean busy;
    private Thread owner;
    protected Queue<Object> urgentQueue;

    public FIFOLock() {
        this.entrySet = new LinkedList();
        this.urgentQueue = new LinkedList();
        this.busy = false;
        this.owner = null;
    }

    public void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        QueueElement queued;

        synchronized (this) {
            if ((owner != null) && (owner.equals(Thread.currentThread())))
                return; /* Lock already achieved */

            if (!busy) {
                busy = true;
                this.owner = Thread.currentThread();
                System.out.println("LockOwner:  " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                // System.out.println("FREE");
                return;
            }

            queued = new QueueElement(true);
            entrySet.add(queued);

        }
        synchronized (queued) {
            if (queued.isWaiting())
                queued.wait();
            this.owner = Thread.currentThread();
        }
    }

    public void unlock() throws InterruptedException {
        Object urgentElement = new Object();
        QueueElement entryElement = new QueueElement(false);
        boolean urgent = false;
        synchronized (this) {

            if (urgentQueue.size() != 0) {
                urgentElement = urgentQueue.poll();
                urgent = true;

            } else {
                if (entrySet.size() == 0) {
                    busy = false;
                    return;
                }
                entryElement = entrySet.poll();
            }
        }
        if (urgent) {
            synchronized (urgentElement) {
                urgentElement.notify();
            }
        } else {
            synchronized (entryElement) {
                owner = null;
                if (entryElement.isWaiting())
                    entryElement.notify();
                entryElement.setWaiting(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code seems safe with respect to synchronization. But it's rather difficult to follow so I wouldn't bet on it. The problem I see that looks more important now is that if thread A acquired a lock, any other thread B can release that lock. There is no check for thread owning when lock is released. Also I don't see how urgent queue is modified. Implementing locks correctly is hard, so I would expect subtle bugs.

Comment: Ok thankyou for your observation, I'm agree with you on the need to check the thread which releases the lock. For the urgent queue a thread can remain in this queue only as an effect on the related FIFOCondition class, which is not attached in this post. A thread after a signal remains blocked on that queue, that has the precedence on the entrySet.

Comment: You should always put `wait()` call in the loop. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--).